# UDF Sum not returning decimal places, only a whole number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UDF which sums up the cells above it, until it reaches a cell formatted as a percent.  The sum formula works, and I am able to have a number returned. ...however, it seems like it's rounding it/truncating the answer.

Code:

```
 Function sumAbove(cel As Range) As Variant
Dim firstCell As Integer
Dim i As Integer

i = 1000

With cel
    For i = 1 To 1000
        If cel.Offset(-i, 0).NumberFormat = "0.00%" Then
            firstCell = cel.Offset(-i, 0).Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With

sumAbove = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(firstCell, cel.Column), Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column)))

End Function
```

I have tried `Function sumAbove(cel as Range)` as `Integer` and `Double`, no results. When I try to set it as `Float`, I get an error "User-defined type not defined".

With this list:

```
25.00%
5
5
5
5
5.5
```

The code above will correctly use the cells 5+5+5+5+5.5 --- however, it incorrectly gets the sum.  If I set the UDF as an integer, it just evaluates to 25.  If I change the UDF to a Double, it returns 25.75 (??), etc.

How do I get it to return 25.50?  Thanks for any tips or advice!

Comment: I'm confused. How does 25% + 5*4 + 5.5 = 25.5? Looks like it = 25.75 to me.

Comment: I think you want: `firstCell = cel.Offset(-i + 1, 0).Row`

Comment: @Rory - D'oh! You're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
firstCell = cel.Offset(-i, 0).Row
```

This is including the percentage in your `SUM` function.
*(25% = 0.25 which is why you're getting the .75)*

Use something like this instead:

```
Function SumAbove(cell As Range) As Double
Dim firstCell As Long
Dim i As Integer

firstCell = cell.Row

While Not cell.Offset((cell.Row - firstCell) * -1, 0).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    firstCell = firstCell - 1
Wend
SumAbove = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(firstCell + 1, cell.Column), cell))

End Function
```

Comment: That'll do it! Thanks!!